# partial str_match between two lists, boundary problems

Tags: r

So I have two lists of unequal size, both containing names.
The first list's elements are unique, clean names, and the second list's elements are repeated names followed by alphanumeric written information that I don't care for.
I am quite new to R so excuse my probably inefficient way of doing things.

So this is what I have,

```
namesfun<-(sapply(Cnamesvec, function (x)(starts_with(x,sapply(MXnamesvec, function (y)y),ignore.case = T))))
```

Cnamesvec being the first,clean,smaller list and MXnamesvec being the latter.

This works just fine for what I want to do,since it gives me the position of the clean names within the list with the mixed names and I can re order and extend the column of the clean names based on the output of my function and then cbind it on my Data Frame.

However I have a small issue that I don't really know how to get around of.
If in my clean names list I have "Mario Garcia" and In the other list I have "Mario Garcia Leader for 1/2f,finished last...","Mario Garcia" and "Mario Garcia Jr" all 3 of them will match. I obviously don't want "Mario Garcia Jr" to match.
But if the "Mario Garcia" and "Mario Garcia Jr" are two different names,then they will both be in the clean names list.
Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated :)

Example of my lists
Cnamesvec:

(1) Mario Garcia

(2) Mario Garcia Jr

(3) Huachipato

(4) Daniel De Rossi

MXnamesvec:

(1) Daniel De Rossi Started well, left behind,finished 3rd

(2) Mario Garcia Was left in the draw stand

(3) Mario Garcia Jr Started behind, finished 1st

(4) Huachipato fast race,led all the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can arrange `Cnamesvec` in reverse order so that `"Mario Garcia Jr"` appears before `"Mario Garcia"` and then remove indices in `MXnamesvec` once they've been used:

```
Cnamesvec <- c(
  "Mario Garcia",
  "Mario Garcia Jr",
  "Huachipato",
  "Daniel De Rossi"
)

MXnamesvec <- c(
  "Daniel De Rossi Started well, left behind,finished 3rd",
  "Mario Garcia Was left in the draw stand",
  "Mario Garcia Jr Started behind, finished 1st",
  "Huachipato fast race,led all the way"
)

ind <- seq_along(MXnamesvec)
namesfun <- list()
for (clean_name in sort(Cnamesvec, decreasing = TRUE)) {
  x <- tidyselect::starts_with(clean_name, vars = setNames(nm = MXnamesvec), ignore.case = TRUE)
  y <- intersect(ind, x)
  namesfun[[clean_name]] <- setNames(y, MXnamesvec[y])
  ind <- setdiff(ind, x)
}
namesfun <- namesfun[Cnamesvec]
namesfun

# $`Mario Garcia`
# Mario Garcia Was left in the draw stand 
#                                       2 
# 
# $`Mario Garcia Jr`
# Mario Garcia Jr Started behind, finished 1st 
#                                            3 
# 
# $Huachipato
# Huachipato fast race,led all the way 
#                                    4 
# 
# $`Daniel De Rossi`
# Daniel De Rossi Started well, left behind,finished 3rd 
#                                                      1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response:) I have used your answer and I get the results in a reordered position which doesn't allow me to actually use the results as I want. However it helped me adjust my command a bit so it will work accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assistance:) That really did help